# Style in Textfield using PHP HTML

Tags: php, html, styles

I am trying to set a textfield to 90% of the container width and center the text in e text field.

```
<input type=text style=width:90%text-align:center value=" . $rows[mysql_field_name($sql_result, 3)] . ">
```

Setting of width in style works when it is replaced with

```
style=width:90%
```

and alignment work when replaced with

```
style=text-align:center
```

However it does not work when combined together as shown in the first code.

Did i missed a syntax ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS rules must be separated by `;` characters.

… and you should quote your attribute values and add white space to make them readable.

```
style='width: 90%; text-align: center'
```

Stylesheets are preferred to style attributes though.

Comment: yes. This works. As metioned double quote " does not work in php. Single quote is required.

Answer (score 0):

Use This code

```
<input type="text" style="width:90%;text-align:center;" value=" . $rows[mysql_field_name($sql_result, 3)] .">
```

Comment: Try adding some explanation, this reads as a game of spot-the-difference. It won't work in its current form though as `"` are being used to delimit the PHP string.

Answer (score 0):

add the apostrophe.
It should be like this :

```
<input type='text' style='width:90%; text-align:center' value='" . $rows[mysql_field_name($sql_result, 3)] . "'>
```

give it a try and let me know..

Comment: I have edited the answer. check out the apostrophe at value'". xxxx ."' it must affect the code.